# How do i assign a value using scanf to a member of a Struct type variable whose array is created dynamically

Tags: c, struct, reference

[Code Visualisation Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/He7yt.jpg)

My main problem is how do I take inputs using scanf to the coeff and exp members declared in the array of Terms which is referenced by a Poly variable member named as ptr and this Poly variable is further referenced by a pointer p.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Term
{
    int coeff;
    int exp;
};

struct Poly
{
    int terms;
    struct Terms *ptr;
};

int main(void)
{

    return 0;
}
//creating the array dynamically
struct Term *createPoly()
{
    struct Poly *p;
    p = (struct Poly *)malloc(sizeof(struct Poly));
    printf("Input the number of terms in the polnomial:\n");
    scanf("%d", p->terms);
    p->ptr = (struct Term *)malloc(sizeof(struct Term) * p->terms);

    return p;
}
//inputting the values
void input(struct Poly *p)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < p->terms; i++)
    {
        printf("Input the term %d coefficient and exponent value!", i);
        scanf("%d%d", &(p->(ptr + i).coeff));
    }
}
```

Comment: `struct Term *createPoly()
{ struct Poly *p; return p; }` - don't you get a warning for that? `"%d%d", &(p->(ptr + i).coeff)` - There are two `%d` and one address passed. Please enable compiler warnings. Then fix compiler warnings.I do not think  `&(p->(ptr + i).coeff)` would work, I think you meant just `&p->ptr[i].coeff)`

Comment: `scanf("%d", p->terms);` -> `scanf("%d", &p->terms);` and `scanf("%d%d", &(p->(ptr + i).coeff))` -> `scanf("%d", &(p->(ptr + i).coeff))`. There may be other problems though, I didn't check

Comment: @KamilCuk %d%d", &(p->(ptr + i).coeff)  - this is the line which is what i am not getting how to insert those values,i have wrote %d %d two times though i passed one argument because i wrote this line casually because i need a help on this line.

Comment: @KamilCuk  PLease neglect those errors ,just show me the code on how to input the values to the member variables coeff and exp using the for loop to the Array of Terms one by one

Comment: @JUBESHJOSEPH you want this: `&p->ptr[i].coeff`. But look at my answer, there are plenty of other errors.

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues.

This is the corrected code with explanations in the end of line comments.
The comments without `**` show improvements which were not actual errors

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>                   // ** you forgot this

struct Term
{
  int coeff;
  int exp;
};

struct Poly
{
  int nbofterms;                      // nbofterms is better than terms
  struct Term* ptr;                   // ** use Term instead of Terms
};

int main(void)
{

  return 0;
}

//creating the array dynamically
struct Poly* createPoly()             // ** you want a struct Poly and not a struct Term
{
  struct Poly* p;
  p = malloc(sizeof(struct Poly));    // (struct Poly*) cast not needed
  printf("Input the number of terms in the polnomial:\n");
  scanf("%d", &p->nbofterms);             // & added
  p->ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct Term) * p->nbofterms);  // cast not needed

  return p;
}

//inputting the values
void input(struct Poly* p)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < p->nbofterms; i++)
  {
    printf("Input the term %d coefficient and exponent value!", i);
    scanf("%d", &p->ptr[i].coeff);    // ** only one %d and expression corrected
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code @Jabberwocky .I got this! .And a lot many thanks for correcting the errors in my code.